# How do I access a MySQL database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

**Background:** I have already create a ASP.net MVC 4 app and a mysql database. I used code-first to generate the databases. The Web App is going to be used as the UI for interacting with the data. However the data is created in a separate C# program. Which gets test data from a serial device.

**Problem:**
I can't figure out how to connect to the database with entity framework in my c# application.

I have already create a new model for the C# app to use. I have read that using shared .DLL isn't the best idea.

this is what I have so far.

```
    private ReportDBContext db = new ReportDBContext();

    private void saveReport()
    {
        string connStr = "server=RnD-Chopper;user=CWXDAQ;database=ReportDB;port=3306;password=QADXWC;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {

            db.Reports.Add();

            // Perform database operations
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");




        unlockGUI();
    }
```

report model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using MySql.Data.Entity;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CXW__DAQ___Record.Models
{
    public class Report
    {
        [Display(Name = "Test ID #")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Test Name is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Test Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Tested")]
        public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Test Done For")]
        public string TestFor { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public enum enumForceUnits { lbs };
        public enum enumTimeUnits { mS };

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unit of Force (ForceUnit) is required")]
        public enumForceUnits forceUnit;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unit of Time (TimeUnit) is required")]
        public enumTimeUnits timeUnit;

        public virtual ICollection<Reading> Readings { get; set; }

    }


    public class Reading
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public virtual Report Report { get; set; }

        public long Time { get; set; }
        public double Force { get; set; }
    }


    public class ReportDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Reading> Readings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you generate your model? Off of what database?

Comment: I Used Code First in ASP.net MVC 4, (that app is working fine) and then I just copied over the .cs file and removed models/tables I didn't need. I can't find a tutorial on doing this so I just flying by the seat of my pants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. You need to add the connection string to the the app.config file and then install [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) then use that to reverse engineer the models from the database.

When creating the connection string make sure to set Persist Security Info=True

Also another problem I ran in to was that Visual Studios kept trying to use the 6.6.5 version of the connector instead of the version that was install which is 6.7.4

so I had to add this line to the app.config file as well

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.6.5.0" newVersion="6.7.4.0" />           
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the connector - http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net

Regenerate your model using the connector, too.

Comment: I am that's what MySqlConnection is part of.

Comment: The Entity Framework manages the connections. You access the database through the DatabaseContext class that was generated as part of your model.

Comment: So do I just need to add a connection string to my web.config ? Then it handles the rest? just like ASP.net?

Comment: How do I generate the models from an existing database?